# Vue slot-props are not being passed through to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been debugging this for a few days, and haven't been able to come up with a solution. I've watched several videos on how to implement slot props, but haven't had any luck getting it working in my own code.

Here is an implementation of a modal component I created. I'm trying to pass a button into an "actions" slot on the modal component, and pass it an action.  This seems somewhat counter intuitive to me.  I would think I could just pass the "action" object that exists on my parent component straight into the slot, and not into the modal and then into the slot.  I've tried this

```
<template>
  <modal v-bind:action="action">
    <template v-slot:action="action">
      <v-btn :disabled="!action.valid" @click="action.onClick">{{action.text}}</v-btn>
    </template>
  </modal>
</template>
```

And this:

```
<template>
  <modal>
    <template v-slot:action="action">
      <v-btn :disabled="!action.valid" @click="action.onClick">{{action.text}}</v-btn>
    </template>
  </modal>
</template>
```

Here is the modal I'm trying to create:

```
<template>
  <v-card-actions>
    <slot :action="action" name="actions"></slot>
  </v-card-actions>
</template>
```

The actions object looks like this:

```
action: object = {
 text: "Connect",
 valid: this.valid,
 onClick: this.connect
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Property or method "action" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in the `@click="action.onClick"` thing. You're not showing us your function, and you trying to bind it through the object (it's absolutely unnecessary).

Here are the code that working:

**Parent**

```html
<Child>
  <template v-slot:action>
    <v-btn :disabled="!action.valid" @click="onClick()" color="primary">{{action.text}}</v-btn>
  </template>
</Child>
```

```js
components: {
  Child,
},

data: () => ({
  action: {
    text: "Connect",
    valid: false
  }
})

methods: {
  onClick() {
    console.log('Clicked!')
  }
}
```

**Child**

```html
<slot name="action"></slot>
```

Example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-vue-vuetify-3jije